# Count values in a dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd be grateful for any help anyone can offer on this, as have been tearing my hair out trying to solve it.

I have two python pandas dataframes, in simplified form they look like this:

**df1**

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| a_1 | a_2 | a_3 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   2 |   5 |
|   1 |   3 |   4 |
|   0 |   0 |   0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

**df2**

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| b_1 | b_2 | b_3 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   0 |   1 |
|   1 |   0 |   1 |
|   0 |   0 |   0 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to create a count column of non-null values (per row) in df1, if the equivalent cell is non-null in df2. The column titles in both dataframes are not the same, but are the same after the initial a_ and b_ prefixes.

So in this example the code would just count the third value in the first row, and the first and second in the second row. The new df1 dataframe would therefore look like this:

**new_df1**

```
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
| a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | count_if_nonnull_df2 |
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
|   0 |   2 |   5 |                    1 |
|   1 |   3 |   4 |                    2 |
|   0 |   0 |   0 |                    0 |
+-----+-----+-----+----------------------+
```

Would anyone be able to help?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: notnull mean not zero right  ?

Comment: Yes! There's a whole lot of nans in the actual dataset, but I specifically mean where the value in df2 is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "non-null" you mean "non-zero" (per your example), try this...

Problem setup:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a_1':[0,1,0], 'a_2':[2,3,0], 'a_3':[5,4,0]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'b_1':[0,1,0], 'b_2':[0,0,0], 'b_3':[1,1,0]})
```

Using a mask we cast to ints, we can compute row-wise sums:

```
>>> df1['count_if_nonnull_df2'] = (df2 > 0).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
>>> df1
   a_1  a_2  a_3  count_if_nonnull_df2
0    0    2    5                     1
1    1    3    4                     2
2    0    0    0                     0
```

Comment: If  df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'b_1':[1,1,0], 'b_2':[0,0,0], 'b_3':[1,1,0]}), output may different

Comment: @Wen If you're talking about column ordering, yes, since I constructed using `from_dict`. If you're referring to the fact that there's an additional value in the `'b_1'` column, yes, re-read the question: "...if the equivalent cell is non-null in df2...". OP is not interested in the nulls in `df1` & `df2`, just `df2`.

Comment: I think I mean. *non-null values (per row) in df1, if the equivalent cell is non-null in df2*, if df1 is null itself, in this case should we consider both of the df1 and df2 ?

Comment: I don't think that's what OP asked for, but he'll have to clarify if I'm wrong.

Comment: My impression is that the "count column of non-null values (per row) in df1" simply referred to the column and where he wanted to store it. The latter half of the sentence indicated what to count.

Comment: Hi, thank you Tgsmith, that was highly useful and led to the solution. I have upvoted, but seems my upvotes don't yet count as a new user.

Comment: As I was implementing the solution proposed, I realised for my problem I actually wanted to count values of 0 in df1 and not values >0 where df2 >0, but think was able to reverse engineer that from this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the a_ df and the b_ df were matrices, you could element-wise multiply the two together. Note this assumes the columns of each df are in the correct order (easy to accomplish, if not). For your example, this would result in a matrix like

```
0 0 5
1 0 4
0 0 0
```

You can then count how many of these are nonzero in each row.

You can convert each dataframe to a numpy array with df.as_matrix(), multiply the two together simply with result = first_mtx * second_mtx, then count_nonzero with axis = 1.

```
first_array = a_df.as_matrix()
second_array = b_df.as_matrix()
count_if_nonnull_df2 = np.count_nonzero(first_array*second_array,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this n3utrino! I used the solution provided by Tgsmith above, but really like this idea of the matrix solution, and must bear that in mind for future problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be

```
df1['countif']=np.sum((df1.ne(0).values)&(df2.ne(0).values),1)
df1
Out[703]: 
   a_1  a_2  a_3  countif
0    0    2    5        1
1    1    3    4        2
2    0    0    0        0
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you Wen! Am going to try this tomorrow to see if it gives similar results, as am working with a very large dataset thats hard to visualise. So triangulating the approach by trying this aswell to check accuracy, would be really useful.